# Dodge two different geoms apart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, errorbar

Let's say I have two different sources of data. One is of repeated observations, and one is just a mean +/- standard error predicted by a model.

```
n <- 30
obs <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = n*3),
  level = rep(rep(c("low", "med", "high"), each = n), 2),
  yval = c(
    rnorm(n, 30), rnorm(n, 50), rnorm(n, 90),
    rnorm(n, 40), rnorm(n, 55), rnorm(n, 70)
  )
) %>%
  mutate(level = factor(level, levels = c("low", "med", "high")))

model_preds <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  level = rep(c("low", "med", "high"), 2),
  mean = c(32,56,87,42,51,74),
  sem = runif(6, min = 2, max = 5)
)
```

now I can plot these on the same graph easily enough

```
p <- ggplot(obs, aes(x = level, y = yval, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(data = model_preds, aes(x = level, y = mean), size = 2, colour = "forestgreen") +
  geom_errorbar(data = model_preds, aes(x = level, y = mean, ymax = mean + sem, ymin = mean - sem), colour = "forestgreen", size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

and use that the visually look at the difference between the model predictions and the observed results.

But I think this looks a bit ugly, so ideally would want to 'dodge' the point-and-errorbars geom(s) from the boxplot geom.

If you'll forgive my quick paint drawing, something like this:
[image]

It seems like [position_dodge()](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) might be the way to go but I haven't figured out how to combine two different geoms this way and the docs don't have any examples.

Might be that it's impossible, but thought I'd ask to check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a consequence of the grammer of graphics, which clearly separates various aspects of plotting, there is no way to communicate information between different layers (geoms and stats) of a plot. This also means that a position adjustment cannot be shared across layers, such that they can be dodged in a multi-layer fashion.

The next best thing you could do, is to use `position = position_nudge()` in every layer, so that across the layers they seem dodged. You might also want to adjust the `width` parameter of the boxplot and errorbar for this. Example below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

n <- 30
obs <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = n*3),
  level = rep(rep(c("low", "med", "high"), each = n), 2),
  yval = c(
    rnorm(n, 30), rnorm(n, 50), rnorm(n, 90),
    rnorm(n, 40), rnorm(n, 55), rnorm(n, 70)
  )
) %>%
  mutate(level = factor(level, levels = c("low", "med", "high")))

model_preds <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  level = rep(c("low", "med", "high"), 2),
  mean = c(32,56,87,42,51,74),
  sem = runif(6, min = 2, max = 5)
)

ggplot(obs, aes(x = level, y = yval, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_nudge(x = -0.3),
               width = 0.5) +
  geom_point(data = model_preds, aes(x = level, y = mean), 
             size = 2, colour = "forestgreen",
             position = position_nudge(x = 0.3)) +
  geom_errorbar(data = model_preds, 
                aes(x = level, y = mean, ymax = mean + sem, ymin = mean - sem), 
                colour = "forestgreen", size = 1, width = 0.5,
                position = position_nudge(x = 0.3)) +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: perfect, I had thought it might be impossible but for just this plot that solution works!